# Can't see data from list

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I can't see data from list when I build a program.

Here is XAML code:

```
 <ListView  Name="alkoholCjenik" ItemsSource="items" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="#FF4AC1A7" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF042271" FontFamily="Sitka Small">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <!-- declare a GridViewColumn for each property -->
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Here is C# code:

```
public AlkoholnaPica()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<CjenikAlkohol> items = new List<CjenikAlkohol>();

    items.Add(new CjenikAlkohol() { Drink = "Karlovacko", Price = 1 });
    items.Add(new CjenikAlkohol() { Drink = "Ozujsko", Price = 2 });
    items.Add(new CjenikAlkohol() { Drink = "Paulaner", Price = 3 });

    alkoholCjenik.ItemsSource = items;

}
public class CjenikAlkohol
{
    public string Drink { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

}

private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as ListViewItem;
    if (item != null && item.IsSelected)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

I assume that my problem is with XAML code. How to fix this problem?

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3040233/4180382

Comment: Remove the declaration ItemsSource="items".  That being said, I'll suggest you get to learn how to implement MVVM if you want to make a good use of Wpf.

Comment: Can't see without ItemsSource @E-Bat

Comment: You need to make items a property to get binding to work.  Binding only works on properties, not fields.