# Listview not taking a property

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm

I have made a list that is a property amnd then given that list values and this is still not working to place in a listview as a itemsource i have no idea how to fix this and get results is there anyone that can show me what im doing wrong here? i am placing the data context in the MainWindow

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="CRM.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CRM"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="1080" Width="1920">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding tickets}" Margin="0,10,1075,0" MaxWidth="990"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

MainViewModel:

```
using API.Objects;
using API.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace API.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel 
    {
        int Counter{ get; set; }
        List<TicketO> tickets { get; set;}



        public MainViewModel()
        {
            TicketO ticket = new TicketO("Jens", "Svensson", "jenson1234@live.se", "0767942768", "This is working but my box is not", 500); 

            tickets.Add(ticket);


        }






    }
}
```

MainWindow

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using API.ViewModels; 
namespace CRM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make tickets public,  DataContext = this; is missing,  refer below link. 
[How can I bind a List as ItemSource to ListView in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039628/how-can-i-bind-a-list-as-itemsource-to-listview-in-xaml)

Comment: i have placed the datacontext in mainWindow i added the code for that to in my edit

Comment: Hey can you check this https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.technical-recipes.com/2016/bind-data-to-listview-control-in-wpf-mvvm/amp/ http://wangxinliu.com/tech/program/WPF-DataBinding/

Comment: Checked it by he is using a thing called Local:Binding i have my MainViewModel in another project that i have imported the dll for

Comment: what is the output you are getting? Also how many fields are there in your TicketO class. If it is only one field you can override the ToString() method.
public override string ToString()
{
    return PropertyToBeDisplayed;
}

Comment: My list is supposed to tak input from the user

Comment: So its a Dynamic List

Comment: That's fine,  problem is it's not notifying UI because you didn't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Refer below link to know how to implement notifier for tickets property.

Comment: But i have fody.propertychanged in my base ViewController